# While loop not breaking when its condition isn't met

Tags: java, while-loop

The program should print "The number 11 occurs more than once"
Then set duplicateFound to true and exit the while loop because it is true.
But it prints "The number 13 occurs more than once" also.

Why does this happen and how do I break the while loop so it does not keep going once the first duplicate (11) is found?
This is an issue of efficiency as I only want to know if a duplicate exists.
I don't care about how many.

```
public class DuplicateNumbers
{
    public static void main(String[] name)
    {
        int[] myArray = { 64, 17, 9,  55, 2, 11, 11, 1,  8, 23, 13, 13};
        boolean duplicateFound = false;
        while (duplicateFound == false) 
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) 
            {           
                for(int j = i + 1; j < myArray.length; j++)
                {
                    if(myArray[j] == myArray[i])
                    {
                        System.out.println("The number " + myArray[i] + " occurs more than once.");
                        duplicateFound = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(duplicateFound == false)
        {
            System.out.println("There are no duplicates.");
        }
        System.out.println("Array length is " + myArray.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you said WHAT language this is. And generally speaking, most languages that have loops have SOME kind of break/continue functionality to abort those loops.

Comment: Your "while" test is not tested EVERYTIME, it's tested when your arrived at the end of the current loop, so all the "for" loop will be done before testing the "duplicateFound value".

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more clear way to write this. Notice it removes what you might see as the need for the `while` loop. It uses a `return` statement in the `for` loops instead of a `break`, which in my opinion is a cleaner way of handling results in loops.

```
public class DuplicateNumbers
{
  private static boolean hasDuplicates(int[] myArray) {
    for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) 
    {           
      for(int j = i + 1; j < myArray.length; j++)
      {
        if(myArray[j] == myArray[i])
        {
           System.out.println("The number " + myArray[i] + " occurs more than once.");
           return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  public static void main(String[] name)
  {
     int[] myArray = { 64, 17, 9,  55, 2, 11, 11, 1,  8, 23, 13, 13};
     if (!hasDuplicates(myArray)) {
        System.out.println("There are no duplicates.");
    }
    System.out.println("Array length is " + myArray.length);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but there is a problem:

DuplicateNumbers.java:21: error: non-static method `hasDuplicates(int[])` cannot be referenced from a static contex
     `if (!hasDuplicates(myArray)) {`
          ^
1 error
PS: had to change  `private boolean hasDuplicates(int[] array)` to  `private boolean hasDuplicates(int[] myArray)`
But why does this not work then?

Comment: OK, need to make `hasDuplicates` static as well. A static method can either create new instances of a class or call other static methods. So, another way to solve this would be `DuplicateNumbers dn = new DuplicateNumbers();` then use `dn.hasDuplicates` - but since there is no local state kept in the class, you're fine just making `hasDuplicates` static.

Answer (score 1):

use `break` to leave the loops. Cause you have nested loops, you need named loops and a named break:

as of the comments: You dont need the While loop. If no duplicate is found, you dont want to reiterate all the arrays again.

```
 outerFor: for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) 
 {           
    for(int j = i + 1; j < myArray.length; j++)
    {
        if(myArray[j] == myArray[i])
        {
           System.out.println("The number " + myArray[i] + " occurs more than once.");
           duplicateFound = true;
           break outerFor;
        }
    }
  }
```

Actually you dont need the break at all. It just saves you some calculation time, when you encounter a duplcate at the very beginning.

Comment: and surely no need for the outer while? that would just lead to an infinite loop if no duplicates are found.

Comment: @Mike: true. can be removed. Needs to break outerFor then :)

Comment: goto's like your break outerFor aren't really kosher, would be better to break out of the for loops normally or modularise as shown in the other answer and return a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your for loops do not test on the `duplicateFound` condition. If you want to exit each loop when a duplicate occurs you can do the following:

```
public class DuplicateNumbers {
    public static void main(final String[] name) {
        final int[] myArray = { 64, 17, 9, 55, 2, 11, 11, 1, 8, 23, 13, 13 };
        boolean duplicateFound = false;
        while (duplicateFound == false) {
            for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length && !duplicateFound; i++) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < myArray.length && !duplicateFound; j++) {
                    if (myArray[j] == myArray[i]) {
                        System.out.println("The number " + myArray[i]
                                + " occurs more than once.");
                        duplicateFound = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (duplicateFound == false) {
            System.out.println("There are no duplicates.");
        }
        System.out.println("Array length is " + myArray.length);
    }
}
```

Another option would be to use a label and break statement, although generally I'm not a huge fan of this sort of unstructured code.

For example:

```
public class DuplicateNumbers {
    public static void main(final String[] name) {
        final int[] myArray = { 64, 17, 9, 55, 2, 11, 11, 1, 8, 23, 13, 13 };
        boolean duplicateFound = false;
        whileLoop: while (duplicateFound == false) {
            for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < myArray.length; j++) {
                    if (myArray[j] == myArray[i]) {
                        System.out.println("The number " + myArray[i]
                                + " occurs more than once.");
                        duplicateFound = true;
                        break whileLoop;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (duplicateFound == false) {
            System.out.println("There are no duplicates.");
        }
        System.out.println("Array length is " + myArray.length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just `break;`once you have found the duplicate.

```
System.out.println("The number " + myArray[i] + " occurs more than once.");
duplicateFound = true;
break;
```

Comment: He will need to `break` out of each `for` loop.